# Getting an exception when trying to deserialize JSON and display the results in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, json.net

I have some C# code where I get JSON data from an API.  The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "count": 32696,
    "results": [{
        "data_id": 0,
        "name": "Extended Potion of Ghost Slaying",
        "rarity": 0,
        "restriction_level": 0,
        "img": "",
        "type_id": 0,
        "sub_type_id": 0,
        "price_last_changed": "2013-03-18 17:00:31 UTC",
        "max_offer_unit_price": 0,
        "min_sale_unit_price": 0,
        "offer_availability": 0,
        "sale_availability": 0,
        "sale_price_change_last_hour": 0,
        "offer_price_change_last_hour": 0
    }]
}
```

(There is more than just one item in the results though.)

I have made 2 classes like this:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    public int data_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rarity { get; set; }
    public int restriction_level { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    public int sub_type_id { get; set; }
    public string price_last_changed { get; set; }
    public int max_offer_unit_price { get; set; }
    public int min_sale_unit_price { get; set; }
    public int offer_availability { get; set; }
    public int sale_availability { get; set; }
    public int sale_price_change_last_hour { get; set; }
    public int offer_price_change_last_hour { get; set; }
}

internal class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> results { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the part where I get the JSON and deserialize it:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string URI = "a good url";

    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text");
    string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(URI);
    MyClass[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(HtmlResult);
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HtmlResult, (typeof(DataTable)));
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

But when I run this code I get an error:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'gwspiderv2.MyClass[]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I already use this type of code on another API without errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you've got JSON for one (1) object, by itself, not in an array, just sitting there with its curly braces. Is it between square brackets? No. It's not. In JSON, an array is a comma-separated sequence of objects or values between square brackets. You're telling the deserializer to deserialize an array -- you're telling it to *insist* on an array. So it looks for an array. Instead, it finds what you gave it. So it says "this is not an array".

Comment: What does your raw JSON look like?  Based on the error, it must be JSON object rather than array.  Maybe you meant to deserialize the JSON to that `RootObject` type you are not using?

Comment: the json looks like : {"count":32696,"results":[{"data_id":0,"name":"Extended Potion of Ghost Slaying","rarity":0,"restriction_level":0,"img":"","type_id":0,"sub_type_id":0,"price_last_changed":"2013-03-18 17:00:31 UTC","max_offer_unit_price":0,"min_sale_unit_price":0,"offer_availability":0,"sale_availability":0,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"offer_price_change_last_hour":0},{"data_id":1,"name":"MONSTER ONLY Moa Unarmed*    and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code it seems you are trying to deserialize the same JSON two different ways, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense:

```
MyClass[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(HtmlResult);
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HtmlResult, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

You are getting the first error (in your question) because your JSON represents a single object, but you are trying to deserialize it into an array of `MyClass`.  You have defined a `RootObject` class, but you are not using it.  It seems that you should be, because it fits your JSON.

You are getting the second error (in the comments to @inan's answer) because the JSON is in the wrong format to be deserialized into a `DataTable`.  Presumably you are trying to do that so you can display the data in your `DataGridView`.  But you don't need to convert it to a `DataTable` in order to use it as a data source.  You can just give your `DataGridView` an `IList`, which you already have in your `RootObject`.

Change your code to this:

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(HtmlResult);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = result.results;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RootObject for deserializing as below, it has the List of MyClass

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(HtmlResult);
```

Comment: get this error : Additional information: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.